# insert script tag with data using ejs (ejs-locals) on express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using ejs-locals for express 3.x (https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals)

How would I insert a script tag from a template with dynamic data?

In my layout.ejs I have

```
<%- block.scripts %>
```

In my page template login.ejs I want to replace it with some dynamic data:

```
<% block('scripts', "<script> var app = window.app || {}; app.err = <%- JSON.stringify(err) %>, app.q = <%- JSON.stringify(q) %>; </script>") -%>
```

I get an error:

`500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token %` -- i'm assuming because I can't do `<%= JSON.stringigy(err) %>` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving the script insertion to layout.ejs since it's always the same.

```
    <% include script %>
  </body>
```

Otherwise, you have to terminate the string:

```
//this works but is rather cumbersome to do on every page template.
  <% block('script', '<script>' +
    'app.req.err = '+ JSON.stringify(err) +";\n" +
    'app.req.q = '+ JSON.stringify(q) +";\n" +
  '</script>') %>
```